# Gzip compression on Stack Overflow and all Stack Exchange sites favicon.ico

Tags: feature-request, favicon, performance

I noticed that Stack Overflow and all others Stack Exchange sites are not using gzip compression on favicon.ico.

I tried to compress the [Stack Overflow favicon.ico](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico) (5430 B) with `gzip -k9 favicon.ico` and I got a smaller version of that (767 B), which is an 86% reduction that can boost somehow the performance for all new visitors and also for those who browse stackoverflow.com in incognito mode.

[image: Size comparison of uncompressed and compressed gzip]

I suggest to enable gzip compression for favicon.ico.

Comment: I’m not sure whether there is a good reason to downvote this suggestion. For a place the size of Stack Overflow, saving a couple of bytes will likely translate into gigabytes of bandwidth.

Comment: @Pekka웃 wasn't a downvote - I fat-fingered the down button instead of the score looking for vote totals (I'm eating my lunch at the same time and I can't multitask) - hence, vote reversed

Comment: @MacroMan you could blame Tim losing its keys...

Comment: Sorry to nitpick but it's more natural to say that is an 86% reduction. Good suggestion though.

Comment: To make this suggestion more powerful: Could anyone somehow check whether it is just this image, or whether there are more quick wins with significant impact?

Comment: What about http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=5b8c5b46a53a?

Comment: @samgak Thanks for noticing! I For some reason I was confused at the time of writing the suggestion. >_<

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Usually all other images except BMP and ICO are previously compressed and there will not have a great benefit with gzip compression. The problem arises in that most of the HTTP daemon by default does not have gzip compression enabled by default for ICO.